# Render JSON object from context in Django template as Ajax DataTable

Tags: django, datatables

I am looking for a reusable and straightforward solution to render a valid JSON object as an HTML table using Django. The flow is as follows:

#### Views.py

```
from utils load get_data_frame

class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "my_template.html"
    df = get_data_frame()
    column_data = [{"field": val, "title": val} for val in df.columns.values]
    json_object = df.to_json(orient='records')
    context['json_data'] = json_object
    context['columns'] = column_data
```

#### my_template.html

```
<script>
    var my_data = {{ json_data|safe }};
    var column_data = {{ columns|safe }};
    $( function() {
        $( "#my-cool-table" ).dataTable(
        {
            "columnDefs": [{
            "defaultContent": "-",
            "targets": "_all"
            }],
            "data": my_data,
            "columns": column_data,
        });
    });
</script>

{% if json_data %}
    <table id="my-cool-table">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
{% else %}
```

However, when I render this template the columns show up without issue but the data of the table only renders the default values "-" specified in `defaultContent`. Am I missing an argument for `dataTables`? Or is the `<script>` tag in the wrong location?

When I print the variable `my_data` in the Firefox console it comes up in the format:

`Array(17) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK. I believe you just need to replace `field` with `data` :

```python
column_data = [{"data": val, "title": val} for val in df.columns.values]
                 ^^^^
```

[`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) specify the object property / source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still waiting to test this, will accept when I verify!